# proper way to measure RAM usage of asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking to use hosting where you get an `AppPool` with limited RAM either 128MB/256MB/1GB  for all the sites+subdomains in the account.
And I'm interested to know how much ram my sites use, this is what I use now:

```
public IActionResult RamUsage()
{
    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

    using (var me = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        var mem2 = (me.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1048576) + " MB";
        var mem3 = (me.WorkingSet64 / 1048576) + " MB";

        var res = new
        {
            Memory  = (mem / 1048576) + " MB " + mem2 + " " + mem3,
            Cpu = me.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds
        };             
        
        return Json(res);
    }            
}
```

and I'm getting 3 different values, the first one being the smallest, and the last one the biggest.

Comment: If you use search engines to learn their definitions, then their values can make more sense to you. Usually the value in `mem` is good enough for most cases.

Comment: Under what circumstances are you getting these 3 different values? Do you test multiple times? still a different site?

Comment: @samwu for example in VS2022 Create new ASP.net Core app, copy my code in HomeController, Ctrl+F5 and going to this action in browser I get `{"memory":"4 MB 38 MB 88 MB","cpu":1.234375}`

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be related to iis, I removed the iis tag.